# Not respecting z-index on safari with position: sticky

Tags: css, safari, z-index, sticky, safari-web-inspector

I'm been having some problems with my site redesign, I have a section of goals in the case study that is sticky and once you pass an image that goal gets crossed as done. As I'm using full-width images I wanted the goals section go underneath and as you see it again when scrolling the goal is already crossed, it works great on chrome and firefox but not in safari. Is weird because when I use the web inspector the element in safari behaves as it should for a moment and it goes under the image.

Does anyone have an idea of what can be?

[Example link](https://ramiroruiz.com/work/games-ihg/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must be a Safari bug with their implementation of `position: sticky`
I've reported this as a bug to Apple - maybe do the same?

Answer (score 15):

adding `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to the non sticky div seems to fix it in Safari

Comment: I don't see any chance by adding `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` to the content section or only to the `figure` tag where the images are. Where did you see that adding `translate3d` would fix the problem? I would love to look more into.

Comment: Here's a quick demo:  [https://fuel.ie/safaritest/](https://fuel.ie/safaritest/)  Simple setup - the first and second divs are position: sticky ( position: -webkit-sticky ) with a z-index of 1 but the third Div is position: relative with a z-index of 2. The third div should scroll over the top but in Safari it often scrolls underneath, ignoring the z-index (and the usual html stacking order). Resizing the window or launching the web inspector immediately fixes the issue. Adding transform: `translate3d(0,0,0)` to the third div solves it - it then always scrolls over the top of the second div

Comment: Just so people can confirm this is solved without opening their editor, here is a version of https://fuel.ie/safaritest/ with the `.safarifix { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }` class added to the third element.
https://cdpn.io/pen/debug/ZExaJKp?authentication_hash=mWkoNYWnoWdA

Comment: That did it! One of those things you hate to have to do. But thanks for finding it.